# Big Commerce Integration for custom Email Invoice

Tags: bigcommerce, webhooks, zapier

I've looked into different ways to put or get order info from BC to different systems including the BC API, BC Webhooks, Zapier, and other systems like Shipworks.... in the end what I need to do is this:

We need orders placed on BigCommerce to send out a special invoice to the customer.  The items that the customer purchased will have custom attributes, a "Tier" and a separate "Unit QTY" which is not the same as the item quantity.

We need to group the items by Tier, and show subtotals of the Unit Qty and Cost.  Send this in an invoice as soon as the order is placed on the website.

We are already syncing to Quickbooks online, which does not have the functionality.

Looking for suggestions on different platforms/languages/email services like mailgun/and even shipping integration tools like shipworks, ordoro etc. that might have the ability to code a custom email template like this.

My customer is keeping bigcommerce, no option to switch this out.

I am mainly a Salesforce developer so my strong suit would be to sync the orders to SFDC and code in apex, send the invoice.  But before investing in the time, wanted to see if I'm missing some quick potential solutions.

Anyone use Zapier Javascript/Python code platform?

Apologies if this is too open-ended.  I feel that this could be a good reference for others in the community about options and best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm your question is pretty broad. Maybe a few links to API documentation could help?

- Bigcommerce API - https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api
- Ordoro API - https://www.ordoro.com/developer

> Send this in an invoice as soon as the order is placed on the website.

I think what you need is a Bigcommerce webhook for `store/order/created`. See https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/webhooks-getting-started.

Alternatively, you could set up a cron job that polls BigCommerce for new orders and then sends the email notification.

Comment: I think the webhook from BigCommerce would be the best investment of time for me, thank you. It seems to be the best real-time solution, and flexible for future improvements.  I am going to attempt to use the BigCommerce webhooks to send to the Salesforce Rest API endpoint where I can create custom logic in a trigger to handle the inbound requests.

Comment: Update: Since I am developing a private solution for our particular BiCommerceStore, I am not allowed to use Webhooks.  They are only available for public apps, so I will be using basic authentication from Salesforce to big commerce and polling for changes.